# Cloud Founry Loggregator failed to establish a connection

Tags: cloud-foundry, cf-bosh

Good Morning,

I have a problem with cf doppel. Using cf logs app --recent I got an error

> cf logs app FAILED Error dialing trafficcontroller server: read tcp
>   10.0.0.6:45719->139.25.25.233:4443: i/o timeout. Please ask your Cloud Foundry Operator to check the platform configuration
>   (trafficcontroller is wss://doppler.de.cloudlab.com:4443).

the same problem with cf push.

We are using CF 239 and CF CLI 6.22.1.

The doppler config is:

```
- name: doppler   instances: 1   vm_type: medium   azs: [INDIA]   stemcell: ubuntu-trusty   templates:
  - {name: doppler, release: cf}
  - {name: metron_agent, release: cf}
  - {name: syslog_drain_binder, release: cf}   networks:
  - name: private   properties:
    doppler_endpoint:
      shared_secret: password


- name: loggregator_trafficcontroller   instances: 1   vm_type: medium   azs: [INDIA]   stemcell: ubuntu-trusty   templates:
  - {name: loggregator_trafficcontroller, release: cf}
  - {name: metron_agent, release: cf}
  - {name: route_registrar, release: cf}   networks:
  - name: private   properties:
    route_registrar:
      routes:
      - name: doppler
        registration_interval: 20s
        port: 8081
        uris:
        - "doppler.<%= system_domain %>"
      - name: loggregator
        registration_interval: 20s
        port: 8080
        uris:
          - "loggregator.<%= system_domain %>"
```

nc is able to establish a connection to the router.

nc -vz 139.25.25.233 4443
Connection to 139.25.25.233 4443 port [tcp/*] succeeded!

any ideas?

Update:
some more information

$ cf curl /v2/info

```
{
   "name": "",
   "build": "",
   "support": "",
   "version": 0,
   "description": "CloudFoundry IN",
   "authorization_endpoint": "https://login.de.cloudlab.com",
   "token_endpoint": "https://uaa.de.cloudlab.com",
   "min_cli_version": null,
   "min_recommended_cli_version": null,
   "api_version": "2.57.0",
   "app_ssh_endpoint": "ssh.de.cloudlab.com:2222",
   "app_ssh_host_key_fingerprint": null,
   "app_ssh_oauth_client": "ssh-proxy",
   "logging_endpoint": "wss://loggregator.de.cloudlab.com:4443",
   "doppler_logging_endpoint": "wss://doppler.de.cloudlab.com:443"
}
```

Comment: The cf cli is complaining that it cannot connect to `192.168.0.233:4443: i/o timeout.`, but you're testing `nc -vz 139.25.25.233 4443`.  Why is it getting 192.168.0.233 and why are you testing the other IP instead of 192.168.0.233?  Does 192.168.0.233 seem correct / incorrect?  What do `loggregator.de.cloudlab.com` and `doppler.de.cloudlab.com` resolve to on the machine where you're trying to run `cf logs`?

Comment: @DanielMikusa sorry my fault. I mixed up the configurations. Now, I have changed it to the right version .

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Foundry CLI is upgraded to 6.22.2, due to that you might face issues with existing CF CLI command prompt that you have installed in your box for pushing the app. please try installing the latest CLI from the below location and verify once.

https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/releases

Comment: Hi vpopuri, thanks for the response. Unfortunately, I have the some problem with 6.22.2.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your Cloud Foundry operator changed the Doppler endpoint port from 4443 to 443.
The cf CLI caches the doppler endpoint url locally, and is still pointing at the old port.

Use `cf api` or `cf login -a` to set your endpoint again; that will refresh the locally cached data.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found it. I was a problem with the connection to the DNS Server. After fixing that it works. DNS was not answering.